# Center an left/right and those elements are rotated based on the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, svelte

[image: card play screen]

I have a component called GameFrame, in which I have two kinds of elements, one is a `table` and the other one is `player's hand`. These are in the `game-frame-container`.

I want to center the `left` and `right` side elements on the screen (table).

How to do this?

```html
<div class="table">
      <div
        style="--rotation-extra-turns: {playerIndex}"
        class:count-1={players == 1}
        class:count-2={players == 2}
        class:count-3={players == 3}
        class:count-4={players == 4}
        class:count-5={players == 5}
        class:count-6={players == 6}
        class:flipped={game?.tricks?.flipped}
        class="players cards-large"
      >
        {#if game?.players?.length}
          {#each game.players as player, i}
            {#if !player.inactive}
              <div class="player">
                 <p class="name" class:rotate={i === ourPlayer}>
                 </p>
                <div class="discard">
                  {#if turn.type == "bid" && (player.bid || typeof player.bid == "number")}
                  {:else if ["take", "card"].includes(turn.type) && discards[i]}
                    <div class={i === ourPlayer ? "rotate" : ""}>
                      <Card card={discards[i]} {gameframe} />
                    </div>
                  {/if}
                </div>
              </div>
            {/if}
          {/each}
        {/if}
      </div>
    </div>

{#if watcherIndex !== -1 && turn.type !== "score"}
    <!-- <div class="takeOrFlip">Kibbitzer screen is here!</div> -->
    {#if game.players?.length}
      <div class="all-players">
        {#each game.players as player}
          <div class="player-container">
            {#if player.hand?.length}
              <div class="hand">
                {#each player.hand as card}
                  <Card
                    {card}
                    onClick={() => {
                      play(card);
                    }}
                    {gameframe}
                  />
                {/each}
              </div>
            {/if}
          </div>
        {/each}
      </div>
    {/if}
  {/if}
```

```css
  .table {
    height: var(--players-height);
    display: flex;
    margin: auto;
  }[![enter image description here][1]][1]
  .player-container:nth-child(1) {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    left: 50%;
  }

  .player-container:nth-child(2) {
    position: absolute;
    left: var(--history-width);
    transform-origin: top left;
    top: calc(100% - 6rem);
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-90deg);
  }

  .player-container:nth-child(2) > div {
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
  }

  .player-container:nth-child(3) {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }

  .player-container:nth-child(4) {
    position: absolute;
    right: var(--chat-width);
    transform-origin: top right;
    top: calc(100% - 6rem);
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(90deg);
  }
```

here I can center a div with some of my CSS (not dynamic), but I want it to be dynamic and if the player plays a card, then the player's `hand` should be re-centered

You can look at the picture, the left and right cards-hand is not centered.
[image: Wanted output]

Comment: Oh, no, now that I see the issue, I have no ideas - hang on, I'll remove my comments now that you made the issue clear and maybe someone will now be able to see what it is your problem is

Comment: I don't think you need all that svelte code for this question. It might be a good idea to remove the svelte code and leave static HTML to make it easier to study the combination of CSS/HTML. You could probably post two examples, one HTML/CSS for the left card table and a second HTML/CSS for the middle card table. I assume that it is your code that is generating the images.